# Run Java process in background without hanging

Tags: shell

I'm trying to get a list of running domains from an application server. It takes a few seconds for the query to respond; so, it would be nice to run it in the background. However, it hangs, apparently waiting on something even though the **command takes no input**. When I bring it to the foreground, it immediately displays the results and quits. I also tried disconnecting stdin with 0<&-.

```
java -jar appserver-cli.jar list-domains &
```

How can I diagnose the issue? Or better yet, what's the problem?

---

I can see some open pipes and sockets.

```
ps --forest
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
  16876 pts/1    00:00:00 bash
   2478 pts/1    00:00:00  \_ java
   2499 pts/1    00:00:00  |   \_ stty

ls -l /proc/2478/fd
lrwx------. 1 vagrant vagrant 64 Mar 23 09:08 0 -> /dev/pts/1
lrwx------. 1 vagrant vagrant 64 Mar 23 09:08 1 -> /dev/pts/1
lrwx------. 1 vagrant vagrant 64 Mar 23 09:08 10 -> socket:[148228]
lrwx------. 1 vagrant vagrant 64 Mar 23 09:08 2 -> /dev/pts/1
lrwx------. 1 vagrant vagrant 64 Mar 23 09:08 24 -> socket:[148389]
lr-x------. 1 vagrant vagrant 64 Mar 23 09:08 73 -> pipe:[18170535]
lr-x------. 1 vagrant vagrant 64 Mar 23 09:08 75 -> pipe:[18170536]
```

I also see the following signal which does not show up when I run the process in the foreground.

```
futex(0x7fda7e0309d0, FUTEX_WAIT, 9670, NULL) = ? ERESTARTSYS (To be restarted if SA_RESTART is set)
--- SIGTTOU {si_signo=SIGTTOU, si_code=SI_KERNEL} ---
--- stopped by SIGTTOU ---
```

Comment: How about giving your question a few appropriate tags?

Comment: OK, someone changed it from bash to shell. I'm using bash. I don't know if the issue is related to bash, the shell in general, or something to do with java or the jar it's running.

Comment: Maybe there is a better stackechange site for this question? It might even be a security issue. I still don't know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following resources were helpful in figuring this out.

[sigttin-sigttou-deep-dive-linux](http://curiousthing.org/sigttin-sigttou-deep-dive-linux)

[cannot-rewrite-trap-command-for-sigtstp-sigttin-and-sigttou](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/227770/cannot-rewrite-trap-command-for-sigtstp-sigttin-and-sigttou)

From my post, it's clear the process is receiving SIGTTOU. It may be trying to configure terminal settings. I noticed that when I run from a script instead of interactive, there is no empty handler defined for SIGTTOU. The following resolves the issue.

```
bash -c "java -jar appserver-cli.jar list-domains &"
```